# get treenode under cursor

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Basically I have a treeview populated with numerous image files. I am trying to make the NodeMouseHover event bring up a little preview of the image. To do this I need to find out what node the mouse is over, but I cannot get it to work, it is unable to find the tree node at the cursor position.

Here is a simplified version my code

```
    private void TreeBroswer_NodeMouseHover(object sender, TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath;
        PictureBox preview;

        TreeNode test = TreeBroswer.GetNodeAt(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
        //Also tried MousePosition.X,MousePosition.Y

        if (test == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No tree node");
        }
        else
        {
            filePath = test.FullPath;
            preview = new PictureBox();
            preview.ImageLocation = @filePath;
            // Display preview
        }
    }
```

It fails to get the tree node no matter where my mouse is.
I am not sure if I am getting my mouse position wrong or i'm using GetNodeAt wrong, or both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter for that event - `TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs` - already has the information you need.

Just reference `e.Node` to see which node the mouse is currently hovering over. If you're not hovering over a node, the event won't fire, so no need to check for null.

```
private void TreeBroswer_NodeMouseHover(object sender, TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs e)
{
    var preview = new PictureBox { ImageLocation = e.Node.FullPath };
    // Display preview
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is at the arguments you use in the

```
TreeBrowser.GetNodeAt(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)
```

Try Change to

```
treeView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
```

Or using the arguments of *TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs*

```
this.treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
```

Comment: I was able to get it working this way using:     TreeNode test = TreeBroswer.GetNodeAt(TreeBroswer.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));

Comment: What @Crispy says is important. You need to do a PointToClient conversion and none of the answers mention this.

Comment: it was a while a go, but my answer `treeView1` = `treeBrowser`, and mentioned the `PointToClient` conversion.